# tweet id of the tweet displayed on webpage

Tags: twitter

I am getting the latest tweets from my tweet accounts by using the js

```
"<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js">  
</script>  
 <script type="text/javascript"      src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/bunswap.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=1">  
</script> "
```

now i want to add a retweet button using twitter web intent,i could do that

like

```
"<p><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=51113028241989632">Retweet</a>   </p>"
```

but i am not getting how to get the tweet id of the displayed tweet ,this id is a hard coded one , i want to get it dynamically

my intent is to display a tweet from my twitter account and add  re tweet functionality.
i have seen this on sites like http://www.niemanlab.org/

Thank You

Comment: this is incomplete code, what exactly do you see now? I can't imagine this doing anything.

Comment: i see the latest tweet from my account and a can retweet it but i have given the hard-coded tweet_id , i want to know how to get the it dynamically